# DualBoot: Windows doesnt load anymore

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, windows-8

I have a dualboot system with Xubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 on my pc. When I boot the pc grub shows up with Xubuntu and Win 8.1. I can load Xubuntu normally but if I try to boot Windows I'm getting a 'peep' sound out of my pc and a black screen appears.

Ive tried to reinstall grub boot nothing changed.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Note: Windows 8.1 is install in MBR and Xubuntu too

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue beyond the grub in the Windows boot process.
I would suggest to boot with your Windows installation DVD or with a Windows recovery USB (You can make one in Windows 10, if you have another PC with Windows 10) an do a repair/recovery (F8) .

You will probably need to reinstall grub afterwards since the repair process will most likely "repair" the masterboot record and remove grub.

Alternatively: This might be a sign that your way should rather go via free open source  GNU/Linux than via proprietary  Windows. Just continue to use Ubuntu. ;-)

Comment: ive tried to fix the windows bootloader. After that windows starts but not Xubuntu(grub doesnt show up anymore). Then i reinstall the grub via live cd. After that grub show up but ive the same problem as before. Xubuntu start but Windows doesnt

Comment: YMMV: 
You may need to do some CLI "magick" to make grub detect the Windows installation. Here is a fair explanation:
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Boot-Repair Disk depending on your architecture
If the windows still not booting like it should is a Microsoft issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: I tried a repair with boot repair from ubuntu. It says everything is fixed but nothing has been changed

Comment: Use the windoze 7 disk to repair the 8.1 bootloader, See if works, if is working download and burn to a cd the Boot-Repair Disk depending on your architecture of your Ubuntu. Still If is not working use the windoze 8.1 disk to repair and then use Boot-Repair Disk, if nothing is helpful you need to reinstall windoze because is beyond repair, sorry